# Running Powershell script from task scheduler when the name of the folder where script is kept has spaces

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, taskscheduler

I have a Powershell script (on Windows Server 2008 R2) which runs successfully from console.

When I run it from Task Scheduler it does not enter the script and task completes with a status of ***0x1***.

The account running the script is an administrator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also show the Action?

Comment: Yes. I know why you want to see it it because the problem is there itself. The name of the folder where script is kept has spaces. Therefore, when I chose program/script , the task scheduler would take up apostrophes ("  "). After a long struggle I got to know the solution. It is pasted in the answer section.

Answer (score 4):

The folder where the script was present was

D:\Some Folder\script.ps1

The folder name had spaces. So when I added the action in the task scheduler to run a program/script , the scheduler itself would put apostrophes (" ") and the action would look something like below:-

[image]

After long struggle I found out that the apostrophes were causing the task scheduler not to run the script.

To fix this , there are two solutions :-

1. Change the folder name to something without spaces
2. Pass the script as argument. This can be done by changing the below:-

program /script : **Powershell.exe**
the argument : **-file "D:\Your folder name with space\your_script.ps1"**

Below is the grab from my task scheduler.

[image]

Hope this helps everyone who faces such problem .